# How to get a podcast episode by its id in the iTunes API?

Tags: rss, itunes, podcast

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/all-in-with-chamath-jason-sacks-friedberg/id1502871393?i=1000538031954 is a podcast episode. Its ID is: `1000538031954`.

I'd like to get this episode's info and metadata through the `lookup` API.

I tried making this API call

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1000538031954&media=podcast&entity=podcastEpisode
```

but it returns no results. I'm wondering if there's a way to do that, or is my only option to scrape the url and get the info myself?

Answer (score 0):

Only the show information is available in this API. You can see the media entities that are available in table 2-1 from the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/iTuneSearchAPI/Searching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017632-CH5-SW1